# How to remove class inside of directive using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

When I use the code below in a directive using AngularJS don't work.

```
angular.element(document.querySelector(id)).removeClass("ng-hide")
```

Don't work, but when I use it on controller, works well, the question is: why ?

Here a example https://codepen.io/krekto/pen/JjoebNp

```
app.directive('filterList', function($timeout) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      // var li = Array.prototype.slice.call(element[0].children);

      var el = element[0];

      function filterBy(value) { 
        //     li.forEach(function(el) {
        el.className = el.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ? '' : 'ng-hide';
        // });

        //verify if element is grou
        if(el.id.substring(0,5) == 'group'){

          //if group is not hide, need show all layers from this group
          if(el.className != 'ng-hide'){

            // console.log(el.className)
            var lyrs = Array.prototype.slice.call(el.children);

            lyrs.forEach(function (lyr) {
              // console.log(lyr)
              angular.element(document.querySelector("#"+lyr.id)).removeClass("ng-hide");
              // angular.element(document.querySelector("#"+lyr.id)).addClass('py-1 ng-show');
              // console.log(document.querySelector("#layer2"));
            });
          }

        }
      }

      scope.$watch(attrs.filterList, function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal) {
          filterBy(newVal);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```
<ul filter-list="search" id="group1">Fruits1
  <li filter-list="search" id="layer1">Banana</li>
  <li filter-list="search" id="layer2">Apple</li>
  <li filter-list="search" id="layer3">Orange</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You might want to give more context. See [mcve]

Comment: @evolutionxbox example code add Sir

Comment: Taking a look at how you are filtering this list is the root of your problem, see a more angular approach: https://codepen.io/kreppol/pen/xxbQyoJ